# I have two java files in the same package- How do I run a test of both files at the same time?

Tags: java, file

One java file is the underlying code and the other is the GUI. The code relies on the GUI for input and the GUI needs the code for performing the tasks.

How can I run a test that lets both run?

If my approach to this problem could be better, I'd also appreciate feedback. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "a test" ? you mean a unit test?

Comment: Test as in to see how the program runs.

Comment: that should not be a "test", that is just an acceptance test. running the application.
you could write automated tests, though.

Comment: If you want something formal, you should look some Unit Testing documentation, and maybe tools as JBehave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean you have GUI.java and Code.java and that the GUI.java contains your main

somewhere in your GUI you probably have a button or something that triggers the need to perform some calculation, that is located within code, so the call would look like

```
int result = Code.compute(param);
```

if Code needs to be instantiated first, it would look like this:

```
Code calculator = new Code(params);
int result = calculator.compute(param);
```

Comment: Yeah, I have it coded similarly to that. So what you are saying is to run the GUI.java, and the java file will grab the necessary code from Code.java?

Comment: If they are in the same package (or just in the same folder if they aren't in a package), yes - otherwise you will need to specify which package to look in with an import, such as:
import com.mydomain.mypackage.code;  or reference the Code class with import com.mydomain.mypackage.code.Code.function(param); - your IDE would normally show an error if it couldn't find the referenced class/function. To clarify, the java file won't grab the necessary code from the other one, rather the java compiler (javac) will link the two with an import when creating runnable .class files out of them